# Difference of consecutive pairs of sequence terms tends to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This seems an elementary problem, but I don't know of any reference to it in the literature.

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of real numbers. Suppose $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\rightarrow0~(n\rightarrow\infty)$, and suppose furthermore that $|a_n|\nrightarrow\infty$. May we conclude that $a_n$ converges?

The second condition precludes the standard example $a_n=\sum_{j=1}^nj^{-1}$, which obviously tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Just ping-pong a sequence between e.g. $1$ and $-1$ with steps of length $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Simple but nice idea, +1.  I found similar solution and posted it before I realised it's basically the same what you wrote before.

Comment: It doesn't take much to change this into the definition of a Cauchy sequence; you just need $|a_m-a_n|\to0$ as $(m,n)\to\infty$.

Comment: Here is a counter example:  $a_n=\frac{1}{n}((-1)^{n})$

Comment: @guimpton, your $a_n$ converges to $0$, making it not a counter-example. If $\varepsilon>0$ take $N>1/\varepsilon$, so that $|a_n| = 1/n <\varepsilon$ for every $n>N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, we may not conclude that $a_n$ converges.

Consider

$$a_n=\sum_{j=1}^ns_jj^{-1}$$

where $s_j=\pm 1$. We can choose the $s_j$ so that they are positive until $a_n$ becomes greater than one, then negative until $a_n$ becomes less than zero, then positive until $a_n$ becomes greater than one, and so on. Then $a_n$ does not approach infinity but it never settles down to any limit, oscillating between zero and one.

Answer (score 5):

$a_i = \sin(\sqrt i)$ oscillates 'forever', never stabilizing, so it is obviously not convergent, however oscillations slow down as $i$ grows: $\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt i$ decreases with $i$ growing, so does a sine value change $\operatorname{abs}\left(\sin(\sqrt i) - \sin(\sqrt {i-1})\right)$.

Comment: Nice answer, different from the others and with a simple formula.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks. :) I found it is basically the same idea which DanielFischer proposed in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence won't necessarily converge.

For instance we can define the following sequence :

Let $i_0=1$, $i_1$ be the smallest integer such that such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=i_0+1}^{i_1}\frac{1}k>1$, $i_2$ be the smallest integer such that such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=i_1+1}^{i_2}\frac{1}k>1$ and so on, and let $f$ be the function who associates each $k\in[i_n,i_{n+1})$ with $i_n$.

Then $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}^*}\frac{1}k(-1)^{f(k)}$ diverges but satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative consider $(a_n)$ defined for $2^{2m} \le n \le 2^{2m+1}-1$ by $a_n=\frac{k-2^{2m}}{2^{2m+1}-2^{2m}}$ and for $2^{2m+1} \le n \le 2^{2m+2}-1$  by $a_n=1-\frac{k-2^{2m+1}}{2^{2m+2}-2^{2m+1}}$

**On top of your requirements, $(a_n)$ is having the full segment $[0,1]$ as limit points!**